# how to merge multiple column with char as a separator(sql query)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a problem and i can't get the output the way i want

> ## table1
>
> ---
>
> **id**---------|-----**name**--------|---------**address**-------|----------**telno**
>
> 1.---------|-----diego--------|-----------texas---------|--------111111
>
> 2.---------|------mira--------|-----------texas---------|--------111112
>
> 3.---------|-----violet--------|-----------texas---------|--------111113

and

> ## table2
>
> **id**---------|-----**day**--------|---------**month**-------|----------**year**
>
> 1.---------|--------1--------|-------November-----|--------2010
>
> 2.---------|-------28--------|--------January-------|--------2008
>
> 3.---------|---------5--------|----------May---------|--------2000

my query is

> ## Sql statement
>
> `'Select table1.name,table1.address,table1.telno,(table2.month+' '+table2.day+','+table2.year)as birthday from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id= table2.id;`

i want the output to be like this

> id--------name-----------address---------birthday
>
> 1--------diego-------------texas---------November 1, 2010

but the query that iam using is displaying the sum of `table2.month`, `table2.day` and `table2.year`. kindly help me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatination. Instead, you could use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT     table1.name, table1.address, table1.telno, 
           CONCAT(table2.month, ' ', table2.day, ',', table2.year) AS birthday 
FROM       table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, use `concat()` for string concatenation:

```
Select t1.name, t1.address, t1.telno,
       concat(t2.month, ' ', t2.day, ', ' t2.year) as birthday
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

`+` is only used for numeric addition.  So, your strings are being converted to numbers for the addition, resulting in strange results.

By the way, you should store the birthdates as `date` and not in three separate columns.  In general, you want to use the appropriate built-in data types to represent data.

Comment: ahhh that's why,
thank you very much for the info. :D